# In the definition for sensitivity to initial conditions what exactly does the distance between trajectories mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, basins-of-attraction

I've seen this definition for sensitive dependance in Modeling Life (Garfinkel et al, 2010):
$$d(M_{t} - N_{t}) = e^{\lambda * t} * d(M_0 - N_0)$$
or alternatively from Wikipedia:
$$ {|\delta \mathbf {Z} (t)|\approx e^{\lambda t}|\delta \mathbf {Z} _{0}|}$$
with $\lambda$ being greater than $0$ indicating divergence of trajectories.
I'm confused as to what exactly distance between trajectories means. The first definition to me implies the distance between two points in state space.
However since in a chaotic system the attractor is bounded, an arbitrarily large distance between two points cannot be possible, there exists an upper limit.
Then what does "distance between trajectories" mean?
I'm a biologist rather than a mathematician so be gentle with the answer ^^

Comment: In general this exponential growth is only true for some initial segment, even if the initial distance is very very small. In many cases the leading error coefficient can oscillate, returning the distance to close to zero after some time. Think, for instance, of conservative systems with periodic orbits.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks for the response! Concerning your first point, the maximal Lyapunov coefficient is (at least according to Wikipedia) defined for t->infinity, so it should hold for even larger distances. Concerning the second point, I'm not too familiar with conservative systems, but shouldn't the distance between trajectories be constant there?

Comment: Yes, that is the official fiction. What really gets computed is something like the average of the exponential version of the (singular) spectrum of the Jacobian of the propagator over small time segment. But as that is not very catchy, you remain with the simplified picture.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Okay so the definition is a simplification/inaccurate? Can you suggest any places where I could further look into it? Appreciate your help!